# How to use component added via npm install

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-chosen

I've installed chosenjs via `npm install chosen-js` in my laravel project.
How can i use it on my page in the same way as i could add it manually as an script tag?

Comment: Are you using Laravel mix to compile your js?

Answer (score 0):

Try working with [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to require node modules in the browser